# Issue loading less syntax with Webpack 4

Tags: reactjs, webpack, less, web-frontend

So I've been working to transition an app from gulp to webpack, and I've been running into an issue with loading our less styles. I am capable of getting webpack to load the styles using the MiniCssExtractPlugin and the less-loader; however, it doesn't seem to be able to recognize the @ syntax that is used in less.

My webpack.config.js

```
    module: {
        rules : [
          // Less Files
          {
            test: /\.less$/,
            use: [
                devMode ? "style-loader" : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                "css-loader",
                "less-loader",
              ],
          }
        ]
      },

    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
          filename: '[name].css',
          chunkFilename: "[id].css"
        }),
```

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):


          &.messaging > a > .icon-container {
            background: url("/images/app/@{appname}/ic_home_messaging@3x.png") no-repeat;
                          ^
Variable @appname is undefined
      in /Users/brandentenbrink/MedData/Professional/ProfessionalApp/src/src/less/main.less (line 272, column 28)
 @ ./src/less/styles.less 2:14-125
 @ ./src/index.js
```

This is an error that I am seeing. At first I thought it was because the @appname wasn't being defined; however, after changing all of those values to the correct, hard coded name, more files started erroring out--this time with simple css (@ blue wasn't found).

I am not too knowledgeable of webpack and less; hence, I am looking for any explanations as to why my @ imports and references aren't capable of being built in webpack.

Thank you.

Comment: The error says `Variable @appname is undefined`. Are you sure this var is defined and available in the `main.less` file?

Comment: I agree with @sdgluck, this definitely appears to be a LESS issue, not a JS issue.

Comment: Turns out, the project I inherited had some less issues after all. Thank you @sdgluck for point out the very obvious